# Decay std::array to pointer

Tags: c++, c++17

I have class like this:

```
struct S{
    void method1(int *a){
       // use a
    }

    void method2(int *a){
       // use a
    }
};
```

To avoid allocation, I am doing following:

```
std::array<int, 100> a;
S s;
s.method1(a.data());
```

However much nicer will be if I can able to do, without making all methods templates.

```
std::array<int, 100> a;
S s;
s.method1(a);
```

In C++20 I can use `std::span`, but currently I want to avoid it as well.

Any easy way to define some operator that will be able to convert / cast, but only inside the class?

Comment: One of the purposes of `std::array` is _not_ to decay to a pointer. You may use `int a[100]` if you need the implicit array to pointer decay.

Comment: A side note: not sure it's a good idea to use `std::array` for `a`, as it will occupy ~400 bytes (assuming `int` is 4 bytes) on the stack which is quite a lot.

Comment: @paolo you are right. but I want something in between ;) I want to be able to return std::array from function and pass it, without specifying .data() every time. std::span is made exactly for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use non-member `std::data` and call it like `s.method1(std::data(a));`.

That works for raw arrays, `std::array`, `std::span` and others.